# Electrical problems after auto start installation

Tags: electrical, camry, remote-start

I have a 2000 Camry, I've installed Bulldog RS90 remote starter about 5 months ago; and it worked just fine.

A couple of days ago I started my car with a key, and could not shift the gear from "Park". My dash was dead, windows didn't roll down, turn signals were not working; but headlights, break lights, dome light, and my stereo were just fine.

I was able to shift from "Park" by pressing "shift lock release" button (small button near the shifter covered with a plastic piece) and drove home.

I parked the car overnight, next morning everything worked fine.

It happened again today, and I have no idea what's going on. I imagine it has something to do with the remote starter wiring; any suggestions would be appreciated.

I plan on uninstalling the remote starter if I don't hear any other suggestions.

Comment: The problem with most aftermarket remote starts is that you have to butcher the wiring harness to get them installed. I don't know whether you installed it or had someone install it, but I'd suggest it is at the root of the problem. JMHO, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uninstalled the remote starter, and everything works fine now.

I've narrowed it down to a faultly T-Harness that came with the starter. I guess some of the connections got loose or shorted out.